# Will Excel VBA interact with web page generated with PHP?

Tags: php, html, vba, excel

7/18/14
Okay -- most recent discovery. For some reason the code works on the server side page when the code is run on a computer with a different version of IE (IE 10 vs IE 8), so I would logically conclude that it's a compatibility issue with the new IE version, right? Or is that wrong? If it is, is there any known remedy to that?

---

7/14/18
I've been looking for an answer for this for a couple days now, and I can't seem to find precisely what I'm looking for...

I'm working on a project that involves uploading specific columns of data from a report to a central location on the web to allow relevant data to be updated more efficiently and to provide an environment where the data wouldn't be corrupted as easily (there's over a hundred people that touch this report, and as we all know, mistakes happen...). At any rate, I made a front end page using html and javascript with a basic form at the top where an Excel Macro would enter data and submit it to the page, populating a table in the page body with each additional row of data. This prototype was working like a charm.

Then we actually uploaded the code onto a server on a PHP page to allow it to be able to store the added rows in a database/save changes as they were made. Only problem, now the VBA will not interact with the page. I've tried several different things that got me error messages like "does not support property or method", "type mismatch", "server doesn't exist"... I know you can use GET and POST methods with VBA, which is probably what we'll have to do, but for future reference, is there any way to allow VBA to interact with html tags generated by PHP?

I'll include my code below and make notes as to where it was breaking for those of you who are curious:

```
Sub data_push()

Dim curRow
curRow = 2

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
    .Visible = True  
    .navigate "towebsite"
    Do While .Busy Or .readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

Dim Shell As Object
Dim IE As Object

Set Shell = CreateObject("shell.application")

For Each IE In Shell.Windows

    If IE.LocationURL = "towebsite" Then
        Sheets("All Data").Activate
        With IE

        Set addRow = .document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            '.Visible = False
        Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("All Data").Cells(curRow, 2))
            Set dataID = .document.getElementById("data-id")
            dataID.Value = Sheets("All Data").Cells(curRow, 2)
            '...do stuff       

            curRow=curRow+1        
        Loop

        End With

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

If I am seeing my problem correctly, the code is breaking at "Set addRow = .document..."
Pretty sure the main problem is something akin to a 'type mismatch' (i.e. html vs php), but if that is the case I have no idea how to work around it...

Thanks for your help in advance!

---

HTML:

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/Javascript">
</script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <table class="table" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>somethinggoeshere</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <form>
                    <th><input name = "id" class="text data-id" id="data-id"></th>

                </form>
                <th><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary row-add">Add Row</a> </th>
                <th class="dateTag"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
...
```

Comment: Excel doesn't care (or know) who created the page. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @enhzflep is correct - once the page is rendered in the browser there is no difference in how the source HTML was created: it all depends only on the page content.  You don't show enough of your code to figure out what your problem is (and the line you identify doesn't appear in your posted code).

Comment: @TimWilliams - agree that insufficient code is shown - the HTML source (as generated by the php) would be a good start. FWIW, the indicated line _is_ present in the original post - it's above the `'.Visible = False` line.

Comment: @enhzflep - oops missed that...

Comment: See, that's what I figured originally is that it wouldn't make a difference how the html was generated which is why I chose this route in the first place; but somewhere something's causing it to break. It has to be something to do with the changes involved with its current php version - like I said, the locally saved html file works like a champ and I've experimented with other random pages on the internet and am able to make it work just fine...very confused... I added html from the current php version... if you can see something I can't, that'd be awesome. Let me know if you need more...

Comment: @user3772914 - I feel your pain. It took me ages a few years back to write a macro that would login to a specific page, navigate to another, select from a drop-down list and then finally download a file. I've tried both of your snippets and they play fine together. I also tried it with the php output of a forum program I've written, again - just fine. What do you see if you put a breakpoint on the line you've indicated and then inspect IE.document? - (using ieObj as the activeX) I get: `ieObj.document : "[object Document]" : Variant/Object/HTMLDocument : Sheet1.doTest`

Comment: lol oh to be so lucky. On my computer, it doesn't say anything. I can even see that the current window it's on (IE) is "Windows Internet Explorer" and variables like addRow are "Empty". It will even let me assign it to a variable (IE.document); but I can't see what it is (i.e. I see nothing) whether I hover over it, use a msgbox, try and assign it to a cell on a worksheet... I've been trying all kinds of funky stuff to make this work, and it's just about driving me nuts...

Comment: Try `Set addRow = .document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Comment: I did. Same kind of thing happens (or doesn't, as the case may be - it just throws another '438'). One interesting thing, though, is that if I try and set addRow = .document.getElementsByTagName("a") up where the .navigate command is, sometimes it throws a '462' error (server does not exist??); regardless of whether it has the .body in there, that error seems to come at random, but it has happened a few times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing, but it turns out it was a firewall issue.